When is an analogy a weak analogy?
I wanted to use the watchmaker design argument for God as example. Paley argued that works of nature and human artifacts such as a watch have a particular property that reliably indicates design. Both objects exhibit the sort of functional complexity that warrants an inference that it was made by an intelligent designer.
David Hume, a famous atheist philosopher, counter argued that the universe is not analogous to a watch in many respects and hence we can't make an inference to design when it comes to the universe.
But everything is similar to something in certain respects and different to that very same thing in other respects. Who gets to decide how similar X is to Y and how similar X must be Y before making a successful argument from analogy?

Analogies and analogical reasoning (SEP) are a very natural and powerful form of persuasion. Hofstadter and Sander's Surfaces and Essences (GB) devote an entire volume to detailing the analogical function of the brain and mind. The question of what makes a good analogy is not easy to answer.
Analogical reason is used quite frequently, for instance, in law which uses a strategy called case-based reasoning. Classically, philosophers have been obsessed through reliable methods of knowledge acquisition such as deductive logic. But, many forms of reason and argumentation don't fit a tidy deductive model. In this case, Stephen Toulmin's Uses of Argument offer us some insights into strong inductive argumentation that we can apply analogical arguments.
Thus, the first criterion of a good analogy is that it conforms to the structure of a good informal argument. Do claims about structural similarity have good warrants and backing? Are objections to claims of similarity rebutted? Are the claims made from good and appropriate facts? Are claims free of loaded language and fallacies like the definist fallacy?
Secondly, the analogy observes several factors that indicate strength. From WP:

Several factors affect the strength of the argument from analogy, including

the relevance (positive or negative) of the known similarities to the similarity inferred in the conclusion,
the degree of relevant similarity (or difference) between the two objects,
and the amount and variety of instances that form the basis of the analogy.


Lastly, the analogy avoid any claims that create a false equivalence. Apophenia, for instance, is a known property of the human mind. Ultimately, the mind is vulnerable to cognitive biases and fallacies.

An analogy is always a weak argument in mathematics, philosophy and science.
One can always object that two cases are not analogue because they differ in some relevant properties. Then the discussion starts, which properties are relevant and which are not.
There is no general criterion to qualify an analogy as strong or weak.

An analogy is no substitute for a proof. In science it is no
substitute for an explanation: Which mechanism underlies the
phenomena in question?
An analogy is useful when it generates new
ideas, which then must be checked independently.

Example: In the beginning of quantum mechanics (QM) an atom was
conceived in analogy to a planetary system with the electrons
spinning around the core like the planets around the sun.
The
following decades showed: This analogy is misleading and veils the
core features of QM.

Paley did not know and did not conceive the principles of
self-organization. Hence his analogy was too restrictive and
premature.
Accepting Paley’s analogy would have excluded further
research.



I might add one more thing: Sometimes, analogical arguments are not phrased as powerfully as they essentially are.  That is, sometimes they can gloss over clear underlying strengths.  (Of course, the opposite can also be true.)  But in these cases, I think the phrasing can be strengthened.
For example, suppose you find some pumice rock that you know came from a recent volcano blast, and then later you find another piece of pumice.  A weaker analogical argument would be, "Both these rocks are very porous, float on the water, and have this same kind of interesting structure to them.  I know the first came from a volcano, so probably this second one did, too."
But it can be phrased more strongly than that.  We can explain why the unique structure indicates a history of rapid cooling and a violent blast by its very nature.  Once we understand that, we can look at the second rock and say, "This also has indications of rapid cooling and violent blast, by its very nature."  And if we also add, "Plus, the only known source of pumice rock is volcanic activity," that's a "causes-now-in-operation" addendum to this argument.
Similarly, I think the design argument has weaker and stronger ways of phrasing it.  I.e., things like irreducible complexity and digital code (including natural instructional language) are part of the very essence of how we understand intelligence to express itself in creativity toward function.  Further, Stephen Meyer has used the "causes now in operation" phrasing, saying that wherever we find things like irreducible complexity and digital code and can trace its source, it always traces back to intelligence.  I.e., intelligence is the only observed cause of these traits.  In these ways, I'd say that underneath, the design argument is stronger than simply, "These two things have striking similarities, and the first is designed."

Why isn’t god considered to possess irreducible complexity?

@Kelly I think the difference is that God by definition transcends nature.  And so He wouldn't necessarily be bound by the law of cause and effect.  I.e., science can explain how the universe works, but not necessarily how things work that exist outside of it, or which transcend time, space, and matter.

@PeterRankin sounds like a cop out tbh

@Marriott Well, I read a theologian once put it something like, "Show me a worm that can understand a man, and I'll show you a man that can understand God."  :)  I guess people could look at it as a copout, but I think in this case, it's simply a realistic acknowledgment of our own finite limitations in intelligence and perspective.

The worm knows the human exists even if it doesn’t understand him, the human cannot say the same of god @PeterRankin

I would suggest that an analogy is strong when its olog is large. Quoting from my answer to a similar question:

Analogies can be formalized with ontology logs, or "ologs", which are structured ontological analyses. An analogy is a partial bijection between ologs. An argument from such an analogy is as strong as its bijection, because the analogy can be used to map components of the argument from one domain to another.

